# How to find the list of current overflow sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-crossover

I seem to be asking questions that often belong to other overflow sites.

Where can I browse the list of current overflow sites so I can choose one where to ask the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look up and left in this page. There you will see the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™. Second tab is what you want.

Or hop on over to http://stackexchange.com and check the [Sites tab](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

The page footer also lists all sites which have been officially launched.

Answer (score 2):

On Area 51 you can see the sites that have been launched and the ones which are currently in their beta phase, as well as proposals for new sites.

However Area 51 does not list sites which were created without an Area 51 proposal (i.e. the main triology). You can see all non-Area 51 sites as well as the launched Area 51 sites in the list of links at the bottom of each page (though unlike Area 51 that list does not include any descriptions).